# Multiple Array pattern matching

Tags: matlab, pattern-matching

Let's say i have an array:

```
A = [0, -2, 0, 0, -3, 0, -1, 0];
```

And I want to see if it can fit any of the patterns below:

```
B = [1, 1, 1 , 0, 0 , 0 , 0, 0,];
C= [1, 1, 0 , 1, 0 , 0 , 0, 0,]
D= [0, 1, 0 , 1, 0 , 1 , 0, 0];
```

Where 1 means that the number is unique and 0 means that the number remains the same until another 1 is met but is different from the number before.. Here are some examples:

```
[-3, -2, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]; --- A matches B.
[-3, -2, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0]; -- This matches C
[-3, -3, 3, 3, -2, -2, 0, 0]; -- This matches D
```

Is there any Matlab function for this or must I think up my own way? Any advice, I am very new to Matlab.

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong about your rule, you seem to treat 0 as a special case (i.e. it is not a number or something).

you could just do something like this:

```
A=[-3, -2, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0];
[ia ib] = unique(A);
R = zeros(1,8);
R(ib) = 1

>> R =

 1     1     0     1     0     0     0     1
```

and match this, this is assuming that you treat 0 as a number just as you state in the rule.

If you wanted 0 to be special case, you need to :

```
A=[-3, -2, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0];
[ia ib] = unique(A);
ib(ia==0)=[];
R = zeros(1,8);
R(ib) = 1

>> R =

 1     1     0     1     0     0     0     0
```

and simply match this vector to your B,C,D etc. The second method matches your desired answer, but does not match the rule you state. The first method matches the rule you state but not your desired output.

=============EDIT============

I am on 2010b and some time along the time line, the way `unique` works changed, you now need to add `legacy` if you are using any version above 2012b.

Sorry I forgot to mention this:

just change it to :

```
[ia ib] = unique(A,'legacy');
```

and it should work fine.

Comment: For the second version I get 1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0 and the first 1     1     1     0     1     0     0     0

Comment: @user1876942 what A are you using?

Comment: A=[-3, -2, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0];

Comment: @user1876942 sorry, this was a version issue, I have a fix for it. please see the Edit section.

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot.  Can you sort and ignore 0 in Matlab?  For example, this would fail 0     0     0     0     1     1     2     3  although it is valid.

Comment: @user1876942 the second method should remove the influence of 0 in a vector, so I think it should work fine.

Comment: it gives 0     1     1     1     0     0     0     0, which does not match any pattern